# zpool 'replace' vdev failed after resilvering - can't detach

Tags: 12.04, zfs

My one zpool has experienced two successive drive failures.  As I was resilvering the first, the second failed and I got two errors, in snapshots. The resilvering finished, and then I used "zpool replace" to resilver the second faulty drive.

The pool is mounted, all data safe and available except for the two files:

```
pool: gggpool
state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data corruption.
        Applications may be affected.
scan: resilvered 2,35T in 19h29m with 5 errors on Sat Sep 21 03:08:24 2013 

config:

NAME                                             STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
gggpool                                          DEGRADED     0     0     5
  raidz1-0                                       DEGRADED     0     0    10
    scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0NJKS           ONLINE       0     0     0
    scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0RPKE           ONLINE       0     0     0
    scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0RPZG           ONLINE       0     0     0
    scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0RQJ2           ONLINE       0     0     0
    scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0RQSV           ONLINE       0     0     0
    scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0T6VN           ONLINE       0     0     0
    spare-6                                      DEGRADED     0     0     0
      scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EZRX-00_WD-WMC1T4095404  UNAVAIL      0     0     0
      scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F118BA         ONLINE       0     0     0
    replacing-7                                  UNAVAIL      0     0     0
      scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_Z1F2Z9VC         UNAVAIL      0     0     0
      scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_Z1F2Z8SM         ONLINE       0     0     0
spares
  scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F118BA             INUSE     currently in use
```

The remaining errors probably point to where the faulty files were - I destroyed the relevant snapshots but these error indications remain:

```
errors: Permanent errors have been detected in the following files:

    <0x218>:<0x7308>
    <0x3a0>:<0x295a6b>
```

I am not worried about these errors. I am trying to detach the two failed drives, both of which has been replaced, but zpool doesn't do it:

```
root@ggg:~# zpool detach gggpool scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_Z1F2Z9VC
cannot detach scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_Z1F2Z9VC: no valid replicas

root@ggg:~# zpool detach gggpool scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EZRX-00_WD-WMC1T4095404
cannot detach scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EZRX-00_WD-WMC1T4095404: no valid replicas
```

The two drives have been physically removed from the array - sent in for warranty replacement - but they live on in the zpool configuration. How do I get rid of them?

When reading data from the pool, I can see the "replacing-7" vdev is not active:

```
                                                    capacity     operations    bandwidth
pool                                             alloc   free   read  write   read  write
-----------------------------------------------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
gggpool                                          19,8T  1,96T    323      0  36,8M      0
  raidz1                                         19,8T  1,96T    323      0  36,8M      0
    scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0NJKS               -      -    177      0  5,42M      0
    scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0RPKE               -      -    184      0  5,26M      0
    scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0RPZG               -      -    183      0  5,55M      0
    scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0RQJ2               -      -    183      0  5,25M      0
    scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0RQSV               -      -    180      0  5,39M      0
    scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0T6VN               -      -    181      0  5,21M      0
    spare                                            -      -    298      0  5,47M      0
      scsi-SATA_WDC_WD30EZRX-00_WD-WMC1T4095404      -      -      0      0      0      0
      scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F118BA             -      -    230      0  5,49M      0    
    replacing                                        -      -      0      0      0      0
      scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_Z1F2Z9VC             -      -      0      0      0      0
      scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_Z1F2Z8SM             -      -      0      0      0      0
-----------------------------------------------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
```

This is worrying because without this VDEV working, the pool has no redundancy - yet I cannot remove or detach any of its two drives.  I am in the process of making a full backup - only a day to go.  However, destroying this pool and rebuilding it will cause a LOT of headaches, with many filesystems and smb and afs shared having to be re-set up.

And ideas how I can force this failed replacing-7 vdev to work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

Steps:

- destroy all the snapshots containing the errors

Then issue this:

```
zpool online gggpool [drive in 'spare' or 'rebuilding' that says online but is not really online]
```

- this starts a resilver process on all vdevs that needs to resilver.

Wait for resilvering to finish; Vdevs will then all indicate "online" in stead of "degraded".

Finally, detach the stubborn removed disks:

```
zpool detach gggpool [unavailable drive]
```

All pools healthy.